# Trying to set up diagnostic settings for an API arm template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am new to ARM templates and I have the following issue:
I have an ARM template which creates an API Management service and I want this API Management service to use Log Analytics workspace in order to store it's logs there.
I have already created a log analytics workspace resource.

So, according to Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings
the only thing I need to do is to edit the API management ARM template and include a new resource:
"type": "Microsoft.Insights/diagnosticSettings"

but when I do that, I get the following error:
"Values must be one of the following values......" getting a long long list.

Am I doing something wrong here?

thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If we want to create a diagnostic setting for an Azure API Management resource,  we can add a resource of type `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/providers/diagnosticSettings` to the template.

For example

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "publisherEmail": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The email address of the owner of the service"
            },
            "defaultValue": "test@gmail.com"
        },
        "publisherName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 1,
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the owner of the service"
            },
            "defaultValue": "test",
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Developer",
            "allowedValues": [
                "Developer",
                "Standard",
                "Premium"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The pricing tier of this API Management service"
            }
        },
        "skuCount": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "1",
            "allowedValues": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The instance size of this API Management service."
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiManagementServiceName": "[concat('myapiservice', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [{
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service",
            "apiVersion": "2019-12-01",
            "name": "[variables('apiManagementServiceName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "capacity": "[parameters('skuCount')]"
            },
            "properties": {
                "publisherEmail": "[parameters('publisherEmail')]",
                "publisherName": "[parameters('publisherName')]"
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/providers/diagnosticSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('apiManagementServiceName'), '/Microsoft.Insights/', 'mytest')]",
            "dependsOn": ["[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apiManagementServiceName'))]"],
            "properties": {
                "logs": [{
                        "category": "GatewayLogs",
                        "enabled": true,

                    }
                ],
                "metrics": [{
                        "enabled": true,

                        "category": "AllMetrics"
                    }
                ],
                "workspaceId": "<the resource id of workspace>",

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]